# Lua string.gsub('The farmer said "this world is awesome!",'"','\"')

Tags: lua, gsub

I'm looking to find something to replace every quote in a string with a \".

I tried this:

```
local te = 'Press "start" to begin!'
te = string.gsub(te,'"','\")
print(te)
```

I expect it to print `Press \"start\" to begin! but it just prints the normal string.

No error messages.

Thanks to anyone who can help!

Comment: If that's you on the picture I'd like to congratulate you on the quality of this post. You're doing much better then the vast majority of adults here. Well done :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape the `\`, like this:

```
te = string.gsub(te,'"','\\"')
```

This is because `\"` simply escapes `"` and the `\` will not appear in the string, if you do `\\"` you are escaping the `\` you wanted to added resulting in

> Press \"start\" to begin!

```
local te = 'Press "start" to begin!'
te = string.gsub(te,'"','\\"')
print(te)
```